# macOS crashes on any sound

Tags: audio, crash, kernel-panic

My M1 Mac has started facing strange problems since yesterday. It would crash every 2-3 mins into login with a pink screen. What I have noted is that whenever I try to do something that has an audio output (notification, test sounds in settings, YouTube, auto-play videos on Facebook and LinkedIn), a crash happens. This happens even in safe mode. Here's the log:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002899ea44): "i2c1::_checkBusStatus SCL is stuck low; last write status 00010108 int shadow 00010100 xfer 00000000 fifo 00000000 for device audio-tas5770L-spkr-left-rear"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20G95
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:27 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 15F4DFDFA9E0154FED96EA8997E65429
Kernel UUID: AC4A14A7-8A8E-3AE6-85A6-55E6B2502BF9
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.140.2
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001f9a4000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe00269a8000
Kernel slide:      0x00000000204ec000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe00274f0000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe00275bc000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1458ec86d
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x61220b77 0x00041c61
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x61220c55 0x00011f5d

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772d6a4
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed6c
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed6c
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed6c
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed70
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed70
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed70
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002772ed70
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe30b5cd3ee0
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe30b459bee0
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe30433bbee0
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe304308bee0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe30b5c93ee0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe30b45abee0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe0027635a64, LR=0xfffffe0027635a5c, FP=0xfffffe4016a23ee0
Panicked task 0xfffffe166a244000: 1794 pages, 10 threads: pid 413: coreaudiod
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe16670a0000, backtrace: 0xfffffe4015d6a9e0, tid: 11940
          lr: 0xfffffe002760ab68  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6aa50
          lr: 0xfffffe002760a94c  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6aac0
          lr: 0xfffffe00277341c8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6aae0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027725674  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6ab90
          lr: 0xfffffe00275c37e8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6aba0
          lr: 0xfffffe002760a5dc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6af30
          lr: 0xfffffe002760a5dc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6afa0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027dbce80  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6afc0
          lr: 0xfffffe002899ea44  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b040
          lr: 0xfffffe002899d5d0  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b0d0
          lr: 0xfffffe002899d7b8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b0f0
          lr: 0xfffffe002899d030  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b140
          lr: 0xfffffe0027f1eb74  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b160
          lr: 0xfffffe0027f1e83c  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b190
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ce6bc8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b200
          lr: 0xfffffe0027f1f9fc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b260
          lr: 0xfffffe0028413c5c  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b2e0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028413940  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b370
          lr: 0xfffffe002841559c  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b3b0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028458da0  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b3e0
          lr: 0xfffffe0028459084  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b3f0
          lr: 0xfffffe002844587c  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b420
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ce6bc8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b490
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ee76d0  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b540
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ef09fc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b5f0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ef03e8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b630
          lr: 0xfffffe0027eefecc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b6a0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ce1bbc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b6f0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027d27a34  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b7d0
          lr: 0xfffffe0027d25ccc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b830
          lr: 0xfffffe0027ce6bc8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b8a0
          lr: 0xfffffe00294d90ac  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6b920
          lr: 0xfffffe0027d332d4  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bab0
          lr: 0xfffffe00276f67d8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bbd0
          lr: 0xfffffe00276102b0  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bc40
          lr: 0xfffffe00275e7960  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bcc0
          lr: 0xfffffe00276006f8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bd70
          lr: 0xfffffe0027719ffc  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6be40
          lr: 0xfffffe00277256f0  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bef0
          lr: 0xfffffe00275c37e8  fp: 0xfffffe4015d6bf00
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[5E9CCC2E-8DAD-3602-9B36-6A976B6F7995]@0xfffffe0027f18000->0xfffffe0027f67fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[11A4640E-66CF-399D-BD06-F13C57BF7D16]@0xfffffe0029a28000->0xfffffe0029a2bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily(1.0.0)[F90674AA-7961-3209-AA32-824D52A0D44D]@0xfffffe0029ad0000->0xfffffe0029ad3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[A41978E8-2B18-341C-8935-2AACD1565F0F]@0xfffffe0029ad4000->0xfffffe0029af3fff
         com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family(1.0)[26651231-2463-3EB6-8707-2DFA83F35502]@0xfffffe00294d4000->0xfffffe00294dbfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C(1.0d2)[4A691C40-474E-3D8B-B4F0-6D85219C9ED3]@0xfffffe002899c000->0xfffffe002899ffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[5E9CCC2E-8DAD-3602-9B36-6A976B6F7995]@0xfffffe0027f18000->0xfffffe0027f67fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController(1.0.2)[9657738B-0DCC-3734-829A-0A516714EC08]@0xfffffe0028580000->0xfffffe002858bfff
         com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio(80.34.1)[638A63E1-4B5A-30FE-87B7-B3EBE37D4294]@0xfffffe0027ee4000->0xfffffe0027efbfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs(1.17)[68644A0C-4527-3482-9B26-6825735D7AB4]@0xfffffe002845c000->0xfffffe0028467fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family(1.0)[26651231-2463-3EB6-8707-2DFA83F35502]@0xfffffe00294d4000->0xfffffe00294dbfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio(442.26)[DA618C5C-BE5D-3DA9-88A9-D984D01F62E9]@0xfffffe0028410000->0xfffffe002844bfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[5E9CCC2E-8DAD-3602-9B36-6A976B6F7995]@0xfffffe0027f18000->0xfffffe0027f67fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs(1.17)[68644A0C-4527-3482-9B26-6825735D7AB4]@0xfffffe002845c000->0xfffffe0028467fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio(80.34.1)[638A63E1-4B5A-30FE-87B7-B3EBE37D4294]@0xfffffe0027ee4000->0xfffffe0027efbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family(1.0)[26651231-2463-3EB6-8707-2DFA83F35502]@0xfffffe00294d4000->0xfffffe00294dbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[DB1AFDAD-1056-36F5-8B3A-5F0B444E2064]@0xfffffe0029808000->0xfffffe0029893fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp(442.26)[A72BE15E-EB89-374C-8F34-B65EDBDD9260]@0xfffffe0028458000->0xfffffe002845bfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[5E9CCC2E-8DAD-3602-9B36-6A976B6F7995]@0xfffffe0027f18000->0xfffffe0027f67fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio(442.26)[DA618C5C-BE5D-3DA9-88A9-D984D01F62E9]@0xfffffe0028410000->0xfffffe002844bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio(80.34.1)[638A63E1-4B5A-30FE-87B7-B3EBE37D4294]@0xfffffe0027ee4000->0xfffffe0027efbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family(1.0)[26651231-2463-3EB6-8707-2DFA83F35502]@0xfffffe00294d4000->0xfffffe00294dbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[DB1AFDAD-1056-36F5-8B3A-5F0B444E2064]@0xfffffe0029808000->0xfffffe0029893fff

last started kext at 680227629: com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 (addr 0xfffffe0027468000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4050.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.141.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.100.11
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSummitLCD 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.AGXG13G   173.28.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   385
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.73.4
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.60.5
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   311
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   224
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4050.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 940.4
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   985.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  16.2
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    173.28.7
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  173.28.7
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 442.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 21.11
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.75.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    3.58.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   16.15.1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR    140.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    540.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    985.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.7.1
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.141.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.140.2
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.140.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.140.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   290.8.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 305577 (Uncompressed 796704) **
```

This happens even when I have disabled sounds by muting it. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Edit: Reinstalled the OS, still facing the issue. Mostly a hardware issue. This happened very abruptly last night, not sure what changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002899ea44): "i2c1::_checkBusStatus SCL is stuck low; last write status 00010108 int shadow 00010100 xfer 00000000 fifo 00000000 for device audio-tas5770L-spkr-left-rear"

This indicates that the I2C interface between the CPU and the built-in TAS5770L audio amplifier is unresponsive. This matches up exactly with your observation that the panic is happening only when audio is supposed to be played.

Given that this is a new machine, safe mode and reinstall don't help, and the loaded drivers suggest that you don't appear to have external peripherals attached, I have to say that the evidence points strongly to this being an **Apple bug**. Without additional debugging (which requires tools and source code that we don't have), we can't even determine whether the root cause is in hardware or in software.

This means that you are unlikely to be able to fix this yourself. Your best bet is to [report the bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) and then to contact [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com).

---

<sub>[Something that you can do in the mean time to gather a little bit more information is to symbolicate your crash report. While this won't do anything to fix or root-cause your problem, and is unnecessary for reporting the bug to Apple (as they have tools to symbolicate any crash report *ex post facto*), it would be an interesting exercise for anyone who wants to understand a little bit more about the failure path. Here are steps for enabling symbolication:]</sub>

1. <sub>Run the following Terminal command: `sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`. Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a permission error, you will first need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection). You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)</sub>
2. <sub>Reboot your machine. The next time this crash happens, your report will have a symbolicated backtrace.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, I have reported this to Apple. Since this is my work laptop, they'll be replacing it.