# Apple MacBook Air 2019 keeps crashing randomly (Kernel Panic)

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

My Macbook Air 2019 keeps crashing and restarting ("Your computer restarted because of a problem" - message on boot) over and over again.

It happens randomly...after 5 minutes, after 10, under high load, in idle...unpredictable.

When I read out the shutdown causes via Terminal it says "-20".
Log:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff00fd2c2a8): "i2c1::_checkBusStatus Bus is still in a bad state; last write status 00010118 int shadow 00010100 xfer 00000000 fifo 00000000 for device audio-tas5770L-spkr-woofer-r" @AppleS5L8940XI2C.cpp:470    
Debugger message: panic    
Memory ID: 0xff        
OS version: 21P2057    
macOS version: 23C71    
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.2.0: Wed Nov 15 21:09:28 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.61.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010    
KernelCache UUID: 3ABF1CAE467593B1DC6EA0674E50332B    
Kernel UUID: 1D1BC1F4-12F1-3532-B69F-61F6683CEB7C    
Boot session UUID: A39004EA-ABE3-433F-A2E5-167D01A080BC    
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.61.4    
secure boot?: YES     
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xd   
x86 System State: 0x0    
x86 Power State: 0x0    
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5    
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x304050400    
PCIeUp link state: 0x68271614    
macOS kernel slide: 0x15600000    
Paniclog version: 14    
Kernel slide:      0x00000000097fc000    
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff010800000        
TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xffffffe0c54909c0  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x000000016f9a70e0 }    
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.    
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffff010a2b008, LR=0xfffffff010a2b008, FP=0xffffffee3ba8bef0   
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xffffffdfde2ed2e0: 438 pages, 9 threads: pid 49: bridgeaudiod  
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0c54909c0, backtrace: 0xffffffee3b8f2a10, tid: 3419
```

SMC reset didnt work...
NVRAM reset didnt work...
Disk wipe and reinstallation didn't work...
Im frustrated...

Hope someone can help me and maybe tell me what's damaged so I can replace it.

Thanks!

Comment: "device audio-tas5770L-spkr-woofer-r".  Do you have some audio hardware connected, perhaps with third-party drivers?

Comment: @benwiggy no, nothing at all. its basically a freshly installed MacOS, without any external peripherals. Just the macbook, nothing else.

Comment: If you're getting panics from a 'clean' OS with no additional software installed, then that points to hardware. Take it to an Apple Store, or other authorised repair shop.

Comment: @benwiggy well i would like to repair it myself, i got the tools i need and the smd soldering knowledge so that shouldnt be an issue. tas5770L looks like an audio board issue to me, but why doesnt it crash when i play audio, but crash randomly?

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426067/macos-crashes-on-any-sound

Comment: @Tetsujin it crashes randomly, even when no sound is played. However, when I play sound the left speaker is working, the right one isnt though.

Comment: All refs I can find to a tas5770L say it's an audio component [Texas Instruments]. All refs including 'Mac' are audio kernel panics, caused by `bridgeaudiod` in your case. My best guess is it's a hardware fault.